# Create command line with echo off

Tags: java, windows, command-line

I've read some articles on this subject, but I've been having troubles executing it myself. I'm trying to create a program that creates a command line with echo off, and this is the command I'm using at the moment:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cmd.exe /q /k start" );
```

Now, I know using rt.exec() is generally something people like to stray away from, however this isn't going to be a large-scale program, just a small text & object-based RPG in Java I'm making for fun with my friend.

Right now, the command line is appearing properly but displays like I just normally opened the command line through cmd.exe. Is there something I'm not understanding here?

Comment: what is the expected behavior, what is the behavior you are observing?

Comment: @JosAngelGeorge Like I said, the command line is appearing properly, and my question is how can I make the command line appear, but as if it was created with (at)echo off?

Answer (score 1):

With `cmd.exe /q /k start` you end up with two `cmd` prompts - the `cmd.exe` one, and the `start` one. `start` opens a new shell prompt, but not a quiet one (see here for more information about `start`: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx).

I assume you only need that one cmd prompt, so try this instead:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cmd.exe /q" );`

**Edit:**

I didn't account for that `cmd.exe` terminates after being executed by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`.
After some trial and error, this should work:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cmd.exe /q /k start title /i" );`

The `/i` parameter to `start` tells it to inherit the environment from where it was invoked, and this environment is quiet, thanks to the `/q` parameter to `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Running that doesn't open up a command prompt anymore. Right now I'm just running this in a test main method, and I have a few println statements for debugging, but with this exec it just prints out all the statements with no command prompt executing.

Comment: @iViscosity after some trial and error found this which should hopefully work for you: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cmd.exe /q /k start title /i" );` - updated the answer accordingly. HTH

Comment: It still starts up the command prompt but has the C:\Users\... and I have to manually type echo off for the echo to go away. I'm thinking of just packaging a .bat file with it that will execute my main class, but I'd still like to know how I could do this.